# How to recover lost message in kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm writing an application in Apache camel. I am consume messages from some Kafka topic via camel Kafka component and dumps into database for recovery in case of any crash/restart happens. Below is the camel URI

> kafka:?autoCommitEnable=false&groupId=r&keySerializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer&serializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer&topic=

My use case is - I have consumed some message(s) from Kafka but could not dumped the same into the database for recovery and crash happens.Now how to get the all the lost messages with the same consumer group ID after restarting the application ? 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the posting guidelines. It would help if you could provide example code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

**Now how to get the all the lost messages with the same consumer group ID after restarting the application ?**

Actually kafka store the consumer offset for you, If you do commit offset in your application. So when you restart the application, It will consume message from the last offset stored in kafka.

You could set the AutocommitEnable=true OR

I also found this https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.18.2/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaConsumer.java.

There are some piece code :

```
 if (endpoint.getConfiguration().isAutoCommitEnable() != null
                        && !endpoint.getConfiguration().isAutoCommitEnable()) {
                        long partitionLastoffset = partitionRecords.get(partitionRecords.size() - 1).offset();
                        consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(
                            partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(partitionLastoffset + 1)));
                    }
```

The Camel will take care of this even you do not set the AutocommitEnable.

Comment: Thanks GuangshengZuo for the reply. But how to commit successfully consumed offset from camel application ?

Comment: you could set autoCommitEnable=true to left it commit offset for you.